# Django, sorted fields type many-to-many in admins pages

Tags: python, django

Good day! It is necessary to display when editing the structure of the field (belonging to the parent) and sort by belonging to the parent object, which is displayed in the admin panel. I am creating a page for publishing documents in 3 categories, each category has a model (also the page itself).
The following content
`models.py`

```
class Pages(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(default="", max_length=64, verbose_name="Slug", help_text="Фигурирует в URL, как id для ссылки на страницу")
    title = models.CharField(default="", max_length=255, verbose_name="Краткий заголовок", help_text="Заголовок, отображаемый в меню, блоках и прочее")
    description = models.CharField(default="", max_length=255, verbose_name="Описание", help_text="Описание подробное страницы, обычно используется в поисковых системах, как параметр description")
    public_name = models.CharField(default="", max_length=255, verbose_name="Отображаемый заголовок", help_text="Заголовок в шапке страницы")
    date_pub = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today, editable=False, verbose_name="Отображаемый заголовок", help_text="Заголовок в шапке страницы")
    fullmenu = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Раскрытое меню на странице", help_text="Отображать на десктопах постоянно открытое меню сайта")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_pub']
        verbose_name = 'Страницы сайта'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Страницы сайта'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    def get_containers(self):
        return Containers.objects.filter(page_member=self)

#Files module
#Tags menu
class TagsMenu(models.Model):
    titlemenu = models.CharField(default="", blank=True, max_length=80, verbose_name="Название критерия файла", help_text="Название критерия файла по которому идёт выборка")
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="Приоритет", help_text="Чем меньше число, тем выше приоритет, как порядковый номер")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']
        verbose_name = 'Меню тегов'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Меню тегов'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titlemenu
    
    def get_itemtag(self):
        return TagsItem.objects.filter(tagsmenuid=self)
    
class TagsItem(models.Model):
    tagsmenuid = models.ForeignKey(TagsMenu, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="tagsmenu_url")
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="Приоритет отображения", help_text="Чем меньше число, тем выше приоритет, как порядковый номер")
    titleitem = models.CharField(default="", blank=True, max_length=80, verbose_name="Название элемента выборки", help_text="Вариант выборки")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']
        verbose_name = 'Тег'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Тег'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titleitem
    
#Files
class FilesUpload(models.Model):
    filesUrl = models.FileField(upload_to='files/%d-%m-%Y/', verbose_name="Файл на сервере")
    title = models.CharField(default="", max_length=255, verbose_name="Название файла", help_text="Название файла отображаемое в таблице")
    tagsid = models.ManyToManyField(TagsItem, null=True, blank=True, related_name="tagsitem_url")
    date_pub = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Дата публикации", help_text="Установка дата публикации в таблице")
    pageid = models.ManyToManyField(Pages, null=True, blank=True, related_name="page_pub_file")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_pub']
        verbose_name = 'Файлы и документы'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Файлы и документы'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

`admin.py`

```
# Register your models here.
class TagsItemInline(nested_admin.NestedTabularInline):
    extra = 0
    model = TagsItem

class TagsMenuInline(nested_admin.NestedStackedInline):
    extra = 0
    model = TagsMenu
    inlines = [TagsItemInline]

class TagsMenuAdmin(nested_admin.NestedModelAdmin):
    extra = 0
    model = TagsMenu
    inlines = [TagsItemInline]

#Files
class FilesUploadAdmin(nested_admin.NestedModelAdmin):
    extra = 0
    model = FilesUpload

#Page properties
class PagesAdmin(nested_admin.NestedModelAdmin):
    model = Pages
    inlines = [ContainersInline]
    extra = 0

admin.site.register(Pages, PagesAdmin)
admin.site.register(FilesUpload, FilesUploadAdmin)
admin.site.register(TagsMenu, TagsMenuAdmin)
```

[Fields Tags ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/462aB.png)
[Tags Menu Owners Tags Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06mfZ.png)

I use django-nested-admin, django latest version, python 3.11

UPDATE 02.08.23 : I just found a way to display the belonging of an element to a category, through the addition to "class Models":
`models.py`

```
class TagsItem(models.Model):
    tagsmenuid = models.ForeignKey(TagsMenu, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="tagsmenu_url")
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="Приоритет отображения", help_text="Чем меньше число, тем выше приоритет, как порядковый номер")
    titleitem = models.CharField(default="", blank=True, max_length=80, verbose_name="Название элемента выборки", help_text="Вариант выборки")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']
        verbose_name = 'Тег'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Тег'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titleitem + ' (Меню: ' + self.tagsmenuid.titlemenu + ')'
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsZpl.png)

But I don't think this kind of view will be convenient for sampling and there is an opportunity how to display the hierarchy, how can this be implemented?